# Java shared library generated from C++ code

Tags: java, c++

I'm trying to run C++ code in java using the java wrapper to generate such code, I've successfully generated all the code and implemented it in my code, but when I try to compile, I get an architecture error

Can't load this .dll (machine code=0x7) on a AMD 64-bit platform

I'm running java 1.8.0_022, the PC I'm running the code in is a Intel 64 bit platform and I've tried to run the code in a 64 bit AMD computer and get the same error

any help to run C++ code in java?
Either to run it like this with a shared library or any other method

Comment: That sounds like you compiled the DLL wrong (probably as a 32-bit DLL?). Also C and C# are two completely different languages, pick the correct tag please

Comment: To be perfectly clear, C, C++, and C# are three different languages. Pick one, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical solution to run C++ code in Java is with Java Native Interfaces (JNI)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/

You might also want to check SWIG that makes the C++/JNI integration much easier.

https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html

As user @KCWong added in the comments, there's also JNA (github.com/java-native-access/jna). Easier to use but runs much slower than JNI.

JavaCCP (github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) is another alternative, it is said to be about as fast as JNI.

Comment: There's also JNA (https://github.com/java-native-access/jna). Easier to use but runs much slower than JNI. JavaCCP (https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) is another alternative, it is said to be about as fast as JNI but I've not used it personally.

Comment: Thanks for the info, reading trough the JNI documentation I came across the .dll creation that I was missing to compile my project